# Community Promotion Ads - 2017

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It is a bit late into this new year, being that we're already in the second month, but we are now cycling the Community Promotion Ads for 2017!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting blogs and websites for the curious
- cool events or conferences for particular movies or shows
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2616).

Answer (score 12):

[image: Interested in books as well as movies?]

Comment: Nice reuse of ad idea ;), anyway +1

Comment: Ad mostly designed by [@BESW](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/a/423/17). (Oops, I should have mentioned attribution earlier.)

Comment: I really like this one, way more then lame area 51 ad.

Answer (score 11):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]
<sub>(source: [herokuapp.com](https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/movies.stackexchange.com/bounty.png))</sub>

Answer (score 9):

[image: Film reviews and opinion pieces]

Comment: Self-promotion alert!!! :-O (+1)

Comment: +1 for the red. Anywya you should try this on Scifi too

Comment: repost time????

Answer (score 7):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Comment: Designed by [Pandya♦](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/770/76)

Comment: i don't understand this one.  is that the name of two movies?

Comment: @DForck42 It's the name of two Hindu scripture which got adapted in various TV shows.

Comment: I don't exactly understand its relevance for movies to begin with.

Comment: Namaskar! I've just tried it for [2018](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4292/51562)!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Come to SFF:SE to get a better answer.]

Comment: Ad courtesy of [Valorum](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10590/lets-promote-sff-on-other-sites?noredirect=1#comment32072_10590). We're currently in process of brainstorming a design for a better ad - something that won't steal traffic from here; until then, I though this wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why four people saw fit to downvote this ad ...

Comment: @randal'thor To be honest, it doesn't really show much effort and looks like a meme slammed together in 3 seconds from a low-res screengrab and some standard meme-font. This makes it look more like a joke than a serious advert. I struggle to understand if you really think this is how your site wants to look in an advert. I'm still waiting for that proper ad Gallifreyan promised or if we're really stuck with this. No matter if people like SciFi being advertized here or not, *this* doesn't really seem to be the presentation it deserves.

Comment: For example the ads presented in [this question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10590/23386) and its answers look far more reasonable.

Comment: @Napoleon Thanks for your honest feedback; I can now better appreciate (and even agree with) why this ad is being poorly received. I may just post some variant of the SFF site background, like the ad we used on Worldbuilding, but I'm still trying to come up with a reasonably short tagline which conveys some of the idea of "many great films are sci-fi or fantasy, so if you have questions about *other*, non-screen, works of sci-fi or fantasy, then come to SFF.SE".

Comment: "Got a genre-specific question? Try Sci-fi & Fantasy SE!" ... hmm, still needs work.

Comment: @randal'thor I have to agree with napoleon, this ad just isn't very high quality.  I also appreciate the effort put forth to not out and out "steal" people away from m&tv