# In the front page of movies.SE, bounty.png is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed

I've noticed that in the frontpage of movies.SE, bounty.png is a broken link. Below is the screenshot of the request.

[image: broken link]

Comment: I can't actually reproduce this problem - I cannot actually see any bounty.png file being requested.  Has it been resolved for you?

Comment: i believe this is the community ad, and it's been broken since the https rollover: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2618/52

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the disruption, this issue has been fixed